# Notification в Alarm

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с `notification`.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;

    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(arg0, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context 
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) 
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) 
                    .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext)); 
        Notification n = builder.getNotification();

        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, n);
    }

    private Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Если убрать все, что связано с `notification` и оставить `toast`, то все работает. А если не убирать, то приложение не выдает оповещения и потом приходит сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно работать:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101; 
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(arg0, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) arg0 
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Resources res = arg0.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(arg0);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) 
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) 
                .setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext)); 
    Notification n = builder.getNotification();

    nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, n);
}
}
```

Comment: если я это удалю, то у меня ругается на Context context = getApplicationContext();

Comment: замени context на arg0, а функцию getApplicationContext() вообще удалить можно

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Такой вопрос еще появился. Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался. Например, у меня сработало уведомление и я хочу, чтобы у меня у иконки приложения появился значок (1).Аналогично, как сделано с смс. Приходит смс - появляется уведомление в шторке и у значка приложения "сообщения" появляется значок (1).

Comment: тебе надо копать в сторону виджетов